# VS 2015 Pro cannot detect Android SDK

Tags: visual-studio-cordova

Just installed all the components for Cross Platform Development.

[image]

However, when I tried to check on Tools | Options | Tools For Apache Cordova | Environment Variable Overirrides, VS did not detect my ADT_HOME.

[image]

That gives me an error of
[image]
"Android SDK  The software is missing from your system. You may also have to configure it after installation" when I click Run Dependency Checker.

I already tried the following.

1. Repair the installation.
2. Uninstall VS 2015 completely and reinstalling all the features.
3. Manually overriding the ADT_HOME where the Android SDK is installed [image] and when I did that, I got the error "The software is missing from your system. You may also have to configure it after installation" [image]

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I finally solved my problem. I manually installed the Android SDK from [http://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/configure-vs-tools-apache-cordova/#ThirdParty](http://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/configure-vs-tools-apache-cordova/#ThirdParty) Now, I can start learning how to build mobile apps using Cordova.